# Faster way to import text file in R?

Tags: r, io

I am calling a FORTRAN program in R and analyzing FORTRAN's output file, which is a little big (around 50M per iteration). For each iteration, it takes about 50 seconds, in which the `read.table` command needs 42 seconds. Since I need to repeat this program 100,000 times, I am wondering if there are better ways to speed it up?

For example, is it possible to let FORTRAN save everything into memory and pass it to R?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you optimized your call to read.table? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes-in-r

Comment: @mnel: I will check that first. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely -- write the file as binary files in Fortran, and then just read them via `readBin()` in R which will be *very fast*.  But make sure you check for endianness, four versus eight byte floating point and that.

If you want a tested library, look into the various serialization libraries as eg RProtoBuf etc.  Not sure how many have Fortran bindings though...

*Edit:* No luck with Protocol Buffers and Fortran per the [add-ons page](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns). Maybe a science-ish format like hdf5 will be better for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will look into those libraries.

Comment: `readBin()` is basic R. We use that to move (big) matrices around but writing a short header with metainformation followed by the data.  From C/C++ as well as R, we even get transparent gzip support...

Comment: Not very familiar with this binary approach. So it should work for output file which is a combination of characters and numbers, right?

Comment: We use just numbers, all encoded the same way as 8-byte doubles. You could do the equivalent of data.frames by writing each column, following a header denoting formats ... but at some point the serialization libraries will be easier.